# Error when trying to get data from a json file

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm getting an error when trying to get data from a json file.

It's KeyError for issuer_name when i use this code:

```
@ticket.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Tech Support Lead")
async def info(self,ctx):
    ticket = ctx.message.content[13:]
    if ticket == "":
        await self.bot.say("Please supply a ticket id")
        return
    with open("data/tickets.json", "r") as f:
        tickets = json.load(f)
    print(tickets[ticket]["issuer_name"])
```

And it's TypeError(list indices must be int or slices, not str) when i use this code:

```
@ticket.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Tech Support Lead")
async def info(self,ctx):
    ticket = ctx.message.content[13:]
    if ticket == "":
        await self.bot.say("Please supply a ticket id")
        return
    with open("data/tickets.json", "r") as f:
        tickets = json.load(f)
    print(tickets[ticket]["ticket_data"]["issuer_name"])
```

This is my JSON file:

```
   {"amount_of_open_tickets": 1, "13": {"ticket_data": [{"issuer_id": 
   "244204285729046528", "issuer_name": "Veestire", "ticket_message": "l", 
   "claimed": null}]}}
```

Comment: your ticket_data is a list. you cannot access list element with keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example. your ticket_data key has a value which is a list and not a single object

```
a="""{"amount_of_open_tickets": 1, "13": {"ticket_data": [{"issuer_id": 
   "244204285729046528", "issuer_name": "Veestire", "ticket_message": "l", 
   "claimed": null}]}}"""
b=json.loads(a)
b['13']["ticket_data"][0][u'issuer_name'] #u'Veestire'
```